# Do multiple declarations of the same type affect compile time?

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering whether declaring multiple things of the same type affects the compile time, such as below.

```
void a(),
     b(),
     c();
```

vs

```
void a();
void b();
void c();
```

Comment: Why someone on earth will use first form? It's not very friendly.

Comment: Balog: it's uncommon, but it's perfectly valid. Similarly, this declaration is also valid: `int a, *b, c[4], d(float), (*e)(char);`. It declares an int, an int pointer, an array of ints, a function returning an int (and taking a float), and a pointer to a function returning an int (and taking a char). It's ugly, but valid C.

Comment: The good thing about anything we don't know is to try. And i don't understand why this question is down voted.

Comment: Even if everybody on Earth did one compilation the faster way (whichever that is) with a modern compiler, the time saved would be less than the time already spent answering this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer discusses why the proposed code makes little difference to the compile time, which none of the other answers currently address.

Typically, some of the basic structure of a modern compiler is:

- There is a part that reads each character, matches the characters to simple patterns (such as “a sequence of letters and numbers starting with a letter” or ”+” or “/* text */”, and packages those into tokens with extra data (identifier with text for name, operator of type +, white space). This part is called the lexical analyzer.
- There is a part that receives the tokens and analyzes their syntactic structure.
- There are other parts that do not concern us here.

The part that analyzes the syntactic structure does something like this: When it recognizes `a()` inside a declaration such as `void a()`, it calls a routine elsewhere in the compiler that registers `a` as an identifier with type `function returning void`. This happens when `a()` is recognized, when `b()` is recognized, and when `c()` is recognized.

The important thing in this case is that the same thing happens with both proposed code sequences: `a()`, `b()` and `c()` are all recognized, and the same sequence of routine calls is made to register those identifiers. From then on, the processing of them is identical. In typical compilers, there will be no difference in the way `a()`, `b()`, and `c()` are treated.

This means the only difference in the compiler’s processing of these code sequences is in the lexical analyzer and in the syntax processor. For one of the code sequences, there are a few more characters and a few more tokens, so that code sequence is likely to take slightly longer to process. However, with the speed of today’s computers, that amount of time is minuscule.

It is possible that slight differences in the processing can have cascading effects, if they happen to affect what is stored in processor cache or what memory is allocated and freed. However, these are completely incidental, the same way that, if a mechanic works on one car and happens to move their wrench to a different shelf while doing it, it can affect how long it takes them to work on the next car because they have to walk over to the shelf to get the wrench. It is just happenstance and not a meaningful cause-and-effect.

Answer (score 7):

I would be surprised if it didn't matter *at all* since the compiler will execute different code for the two cases, but it's impossible to guess which one would be faster, and whether one would be consistently faster than the other.

I would also be surprised if it were possible to measure the difference in any meaningful way, as it would most likely never be a question of more than a few microseconds.

If you're having problems with compilation time, declaration style is not the cause.

Comment: Also, the minute differences would probably differ between compilers.

Answer (score 6):

Not appreciably. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I'd advise using the second form as a matter of style, but the difference in compile time is not likely to be significant at all, and your time is better spent worrying about your actual code, the amount of code you're #include-ing, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

There is not much of a difference in Compile time. But its better to use the 2nd one because its more standard, readable and understandable. 
Will try to edit this answer with reference about compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Why would one go for 1st option ?

Both seem to take same time for me since it's declaration. Compiler will take each as 3 void even void is written once thrice. But will look into compile time in detail.

But seriously, a **Programmer** will go for second since it's upto mark of code writing standards leading to beauty of code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's the same . No one will write the first edition

Comment: at least let's hope it will never survives a review

Answer (score 0):

Question worth asking. If you keep the habit to go and see how your compiler actually transforms your C++ code into assembly, this is easier to answer: the two definitions will output the exact same assembly code.
For example I have compiled a little test (using input and output to avoid constant-folding optimization), and the two versions output the same exact binary (bytewise identical).

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a << b;
}

#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a;
    int b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a << b;
}
```

If you go see the disassembly, you will see the int declarations are compiled to something like:

```
0x100000ef6:  movq   %rsi, -16(%rbp)
```

Whatever the syntax you use to tell it, there is only one way to reserve variable space at the assembly level. All compilers will reserve local variable space in only one instruction.

Comment: It seems you are answering from the perspective of run time, but the question is about compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same but it is always good to use the second one so that the code will be more structured, readable and will be easy to understand by some other person other than you. The first one will add more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer on a short question: No.